# Cannot Cast HibernateQuery resuly list to Object class

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sessionfactory

I am using the following query to fetch data from db in hibernate

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select name,addr1,addr2,postal_code,country,email," +
                "tel1,tel2,HeadOffice_id,Subscription_id from Restaurant " +
                "where id=" +id);
session.getTransaction().commit();
Restaurant rest = (Restaurant)result.get(0);
```

But this is returning exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.hibernate.model.Restaurant
```

I also tried this way as well not sure whats doing

```
AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();  
config.addAnnotatedClass(Restaurant.class);  
SessionFactory factory= config.configure().buildSessionFactory();  
Session session =factory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select name,addr1,addr2,postal_code,country,email," +
                    "tel1,tel2,HeadOffice_id,Subscription_id from Restaurant " +
                    "where id=" +id);
java.util.List<Restaurant> result = (List<Restaurant>)q.list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
Restaurant rest = (Restaurant)result.get(0);
```

Again I am getting the same exception. How can i do this with hibernate?

Thanks

Comment: It says that it cannot cast `Object[]` to `Restaurant`, probably because you have selected individual attributes of your Restaurant

Comment: Sorry, Can u explain please? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query doesn't return instances of the Restaurant entity. It returns individual fields from this entity. The result of such a query is a `List<Object[]>`, each `Object[]` containing all the selected fields.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select:

> Queries can return multiple objects and/or properties as an array of type Object[]:

If you want your query to returninstances of Restaurant, it should be

```
select r from Restaurant r where id = :id
```

And please, don't use concatenation to pass your parameter. Use named parameters as the above query.

Comment: I tried thius way and it works Query q = session.createQuery("from Restaurant  where id = :id");
         q.setInteger("id", id); Can I use createSQLQuery and achieve the same result?

Comment: Why do you want to use a SQL query since this HQL query does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

as simple as:

```
Restaurant rest = (Restaurant)session.get(Restaurant.class, id);
```